# Update bucket created in Terraform file results in BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to add a policy to a bucket I create earlier on in my Terraform file.

However, this errors with

> Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous
>   request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.

How can I amend my .tf file to create the bucket, then update it?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "my-new-bucket-123"
  acl    = "public-read"

  region = "eu-west-1"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_bucket_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_bucket_policy_document.json}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`aws_s3_bucket_policy` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_policy.html) to add a bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my_tf_test_bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "b" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.b.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MYBUCKETPOLICY",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_tf_test_bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "8.8.8.8/32"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

But if you are doing this at the same time then it's probably worth just inlining this into the original `aws_s3_bucket` resource like this:

```
locals {
  bucket_name = "my-new-bucket-123"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${local.bucket_name}"
  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_bucket_policy_document.json}"

  region = "eu-west-1"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_bucket_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}/*"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This builds the S3 ARN in the bucket policy by hand to avoid a potential cycle error from trying to reference the output `arn` from the `aws_s3_bucket` resource.

If you had created the bucket without the policy (by applying the Terraform without the policy resource) then adding the `policy` argument to the `aws_s3_bucket` resource will then cause Terraform to detect the drift and the plan will show an update to the bucket, adding the policy.

---

It's probably worth noting that your canned ACL used in the `acl` of the `aws_s3_bucket` resource is overlapping with your policy and is unnecessary. You could use either the policy or the canned ACL to allow your S3 bucket to be read by all but the `public-read` ACL also allows your bucket contents to be anonymously listed like old school Apache directory listings which isn't what most people want.

Comment: This creates a cyclical dependency error where `aws_iam_policy_document` is dependent on `aws_s3_bucket` and vice versa.

Comment: Ack, sorry, missed that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

When setting up terraform to use s3 as a backend for the first time with a config similar to below:

```
# backend.tf

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket            = "<bucket_name>"
    region            = "eu-west-2"
    key               = "state"
    dynamodb_endpoint = "https://dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    dynamodb_table    = "<table_name>"
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "<bucket_label>" {
  bucket = "<bucket_name>"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

After creating the s3 bucket manually in the [AWS console](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/bucket/create), run the following command to update the terraform state to inform it that the s3 bucket already exists:

`terraform import aws_s3_bucket.<bucket_label> <bucket_name>`

The s3 bucket will now be in your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.

Comment: awesome.,.. been looking all over for this.. thanks dude